# Check if a control is loaded in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method that will allow me to set focus on a Control.  I've written the method below which works fine, however if the control is already loaded then obviously hooking up the `Loaded` event isn't going to be any use - I also need a way to check if the control has been loaded so I can simply run the `Focus()` code without hooking up the event.

Is there any way to simulate an `IsLoaded` property on a control?

```
public static void SetFocus(this Control control)
{
    // return if the control is not visible
    if (control.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) { return; }

    control.Loaded += (sender, routedeventArgs) =>
        {
            // focus the Silverlight plugin first
            System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();

            control.IsTabStop = true; // required to allow Focus
            control.Focus();

            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)control).SelectAll();
            }
        };
}
```

**EDIT:** As per ColinE's answer below, I implemented it like this:

```
public static void SetFocus(this Control control)
{
    // return if the control is not visible
    if (control.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) { return; }

    if (control.Descendants().Count() > 0)
    {
        // already loaded, just set focus and return
        SetFocusDelegate(control);
        return;
    }

    // not loaded, wait for load before setting focus
    control.Loaded += (sender, routedeventArgs) =>
    {
        SetFocusDelegate(control);
    };
}

public static void SetFocusDelegate(Control control)
{
    // focus the Silverlight plugin first
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();

    control.IsTabStop = true; // required to allow Focus
    control.Focus();

    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)control).SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Descendants().Count() > 0`, because that implies counting through **each** item. You really just want to know whether there is at least one, so replace that code with `Descendants().Any()`. (`Any` is an extension method in `System.Linq.Enumerable` and works on any `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: Good point @base2, I'll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a control has not been loaded, then the various elements within its template will not have been constructed. Using [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) you can confirm this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(control.Descendants().Count());

control.Loaded += (s, e) =>
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(foo.Descendants().Count());
  };
```

The first debug output should show '0', the second will be a number >0 which indicates the number of child elements of the control once the template has been applied.

Comment: That looks very interesting... however, does that not deal more with checking whether a control is _not_ loaded (has `Descendants().Count() == 0`)?  Or does `Descendants().Count()` only get updated once _all_ children are loaded (so it can be assumed that `Count() > 0` is the equivalent of the control being loaded).  My thought is that, if the children of the control are in the process of loading then `Count()` will be greater than zero, but if they haven't all finished loading then the parent control will not have officially loaded.

Comment: I think it is atomic, i.e. the controls template will be parsed and the elements created on the UI thread, so once the creation process is over, you will find all of the element defined in the template have been added to the visual tree.

Comment: `control.Descendants()` doesn't appear to expose a `Count()` method when I try to use it in my `SetFocus()` extension method.

Comment: You need to "include System.Linq"

Comment: Cheers mate, that works a treat!  `Count()` is zero on first load, but when calling `SetFocus()` on a button click `Count()` returns a positive integer. I reckon that solution is full of win :)

Answer (score 2):

or it is enough to check the parent:

```
var parent = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control);
```

if the parent is null, then the control is not loaded (because it doesn't have a parent in a visual tree)